# Linq to Add column values in datagrid based on the value of another column in c# windows

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid

I have a datagrid with many columns. Below are two of those columns. I need to add up the count values for P and F values of P/F column seperately and compare them.for P the sum is 3 and for F it is 7. I need to display the sum with greater value. Is there any way i can achieve dis.

### P/F | Count

```
P   | 2

P   | 1

F   | 5

F   | 2
```

Using Linq

```
 var p_sum = from p_col in dataGridView1 // am getting error here(group by not found)
 group p_col  by p_col.Status into g 
 select g.Sum(p => p.weightagepercent) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one could help:

```
var p_sum = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
             group row by row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString() into g
             select g.Sum(p => (int)p.Cells["Count"].Value)
            ).Max();
```

It starts by reading the row collection of the datagridview instead of the whole datagridview, then sum the "Count" grouping by the value of "Status" cell, finally select the greatest sum.